# Proving non-linear mapping is invertible using partial derivatives only

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Given $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, it's possible to show that $f$ is a bijection by considering its derivatives only: if the derivative is always positive or always negative, then the function is strictly monotonic and is therefore invertible.

Is there a similar route to demonstrating that $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is invertible given knowledge of the partial derivatives of $g$ only and without assuming that $g$ is linear? I assume that demonstrating that each component $g_i$ is strictly monotonic in each argument $x_j$ would be sufficient - would anything less do? I've considered demonstrating that each component $g_i$ is strictly monotonic in only the corresponding argument $x_i$, but I'm unsure whether this is valid.

Comment: The exponential function is not a bijection but is monotone increasing.

Comment: $f(x) = e^x$ has positive derivative everywhere. And it is strictly monotonic. But it is not a bijection, because it is not a surjection.

Comment: Your statement is true locally however. What you probably want is the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem), which is a statement about the existence of local inverses - not global.

Comment: @ Lee Mosher: Good point. I suppose that, more precisely, I want to demonstrate that the function is *invertible*, not a bijection. I will correct this

Comment: [This answer](http://mathoverflow.net/q/47612) seems helpful when considering globally invertible smooth functions.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820156/can-we-determine-the-injectivity-of-a-map-mathbbrn-rightarrow-mathbbrn/1820259#1820259) and its answers.

Comment: Note that, in the usual terminology, invertible implies bijective. You mean injective, i.e. one to one.